# How to use a variable of a class in another C#?

Tags: c#

I'm working on a C# program that read values from textboxes and assign them to some variables in 2 classes named `Tfluid` and `Twell`.
I reference them in another class named `Tcalc` and do some calculations on them. Now I want to use the initial values that I got from textboxes filled by the user in another form named "Graph". How can I use the values without resetting them to 0 which messes the calculation.

this is how I get the values from user:

```
  TWell well = new TWell(Convert.ToDouble(textwelldia.Text),
            Convert.ToDouble(textdepth.Text),
            Convert.ToDouble(textwellheadP.Text),
            Convert.ToDouble(texttemp.Text));
  TFluid fluid = new TFluid(Convert.ToDouble(textmaxoilflow.Text),
            Convert.ToDouble(textgor.Text),
            Convert.ToDouble(textliqdens.Text),
            Convert.ToDouble(textgasdens.Text),
            Convert.ToDouble(textoilvisc.Text),
            Convert.ToDouble(textgasvisc.Text),
            Convert.ToDouble(textten.Text));`
```

and this is my code in another form :

```
     var chart = chart1.ChartAreas[0];
       chart.AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "";
       chart.AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = "";
       chart.AxisY.LabelStyle.IsEndLabelVisible = true;
       chart.AxisX.Minimum = 0;
       chart.AxisX.Maximum =TFluid fluid.oilfowratemax; //erorr here
       chart.AxisY.Minimum = 0;
      chart.AxisY.Maximum = (TWell well.wellheadpressure)*10; //erorr here`
```

Comment: What error did you get there? Please show the definition of TWell and TFluid.

Answer (score -1):

I suppose, you are trying to pass values from one form to another. For this you can approach in two ways:

1. As suggested by SGKoishi, you need to add one Static class with public access which will have static properties `TFluid` and `TWell` with public access. You can use these properties in other class directly.
2. You can try Session variable to pass values from one form to another. Session variable are stored in Server side memory. You can store class objects in session variable by doing `Session["TWell"] = well;`   `Session["TFluid"] = fluid`.

   And in other class, where you want these values, use `Twell well = Session["TWell"];`  `TFluid fluid = Session["TFluid"];`. Now you can use these object values as you wanted.

For more details on Session management, check below links 
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/225740/introduction-of-session-in-Asp-Net/ 
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/484ad3/session-state-in-Asp-Net/

Note: Session management is usefull only with WebForms. If you are working with WinForms, this will not help you.

Comment: What makes you think that the question is about ASP.NET?